# Problem opening wizard in eclipse while opening the dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am getting an error while opening the dynamic web project the dialogue box saying problem opening wizard and the selection wizard could not be started.
Can anyone please help me in this issue.
Thanks..
Error details -

`The selection wizard vould not be started. Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to Instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.webProjectWizard". Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
I am using eclipse 2020-12 version and tomcat 9.0 version

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: @howlger error is clear to you now ?

Comment: Please follow my description exactly. I asked you for the full(!) error formatted as _Sample Code_(!). Eclipse 2020-12 is 10 releases behind. This might be the cause. Please always make sure your software is up to date before asking.